# How to load Libreoffice jars dynamically in modulairzed java 11 application without getting a ClassCastException from custom class loader

Tags: java, classloader, libreoffice, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to load and access the libreoffice uno jars from a modular java 11 application at run time.

To use the libreoffice classes at compile time and to avoid a problem with split packages, we merged all jars together into a [single one](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/blob/master/lib/libreoffice.jar) with an automatic module name `org.jabref.thirdparty.libreoffice`.

To load the jars from the libreoffice installation directory (e.g. `C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\classes` To ensure that the jars are loaded from the program files and not from my module path I created a custom Classloader.

```
   URL[] urls = jarUrls.toArray(new URL[3]);
    Class<Bootstrap> clazz  = (Class<Bootstrap>) Class.forName("com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap", true, new ChildFirstClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader()));
    Boostrap boot = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    XComponentContext xContext = boot.bootstrap():
```

Now this gives me the following error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap cannot be cast to class com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap (com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap is in unnamed module of loader org.jabref.logic.openoffice.ChildFirstClassLoader @13c4b54c; com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap is in module org.jabref.thirdparty.libreoffice of loader 'app')
```

I do understand the problem here and read a lot of things about this, but could not find a solution to this problem. The key problem is that I must use the jars from the LO folder, because otherwise it won't find the libreoffice instance. I thought about putting the modularized jar into the LO folder as well, but not sure if that would work.

Under Java 8 we used the typical "reflection + addUrls" approach cause all was on the classpath.

This is the custom class laoder:

```
public class ChildFirstClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    public ChildFirstClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(urls, parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // has the class loaded already?
        Class<?> loadedClass = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (loadedClass == null) {
            try {
                // find the class from given jar urls 
                loadedClass = findClass(name);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // Hmmm... class does not exist in the given urls.
                // Let's try finding it in our parent classloader.
                // this'll throw ClassNotFoundException in failure.                  
                loadedClass = super.loadClass(name, resolve);
            }
        }
        if (resolve) { // marked to resolve
            resolveClass(loadedClass);
        }
        return loadedClass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with LibreOffice 7.0, there is now a combined libreoffice.jar which works with the Java module system.

Comment: Kind of late, but where is this info documented? I'm only just beginning to look into programming LibreOffice from Java, and this absolutely basic information is missing in the documentation as far as I can see. I've been looking here (https://api.libreoffice.org/) and here (https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/DevGuide) so far...are there any better basic guides?

Comment: Yes, documentation not as good as it could be.
This page has some helpful resources: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Extension_Development
Esp. this starter project is a good starting point: https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension